# The group cohomology of the character group

Tags: group-theory, characters, group-cohomology

Let  $G$ be  an abelian group and $M$  be  a  $G$-module. The  group of complex  valued  characters  of  $M$  is  denoted  by $\widehat M$. There is  an obvious  $G$-module  structure  on $\widehat M$.

Is there any relation between group cohomologies $H^n(G,M)$ and  $H^n(G,\widehat M)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$H^n(G,\widehat{M})\cong {H_n(G,M)}^{\widehat{\hphantom{u}}}$$
This is Proposition IV.7.1 in Brown's *Cohomology of Groups*.
This comes from a pairing
$$H^n(G,\widehat M)\times H_n(G,M)\to\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z.$$

Comment: I modified the second hat, since I almost missed it in the first read. Perhaps a $\wedge$ would be better?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff   I  did the same in my question.Thanks.

Comment: @Lord  Thanks  for  your  very helpful answer.